# Can a non-UFD quadratic integer ring have some irreducible numbers that are actually prime?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

And if so, is there an efficient way to identify such primes?

For example, in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, it's clear that $17$ is irreducible. Among its first fifty multiples ($34$ through $850$) I was unable to find a single example of a number of the form $x^2 + 5y^2$, but of course this doesn't guarantee no such multiple exists. This method would be horrendously inefficient if it turns out that the sought-for multiple is quite large.

"My" tutor said ideals might give the answer here, but didn't elaborate, plus I'm only barely beginning to understand ideals in PIDs, which $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ of course is not.

Comment: To show that $17$ is not of that form, just reduce modulo $5$ and use the fact that $2$ is not a square mod $5$

Comment: That kind of number crunching is not the most efficient, but there are some optimizations that can be applied. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has class number 2. So if there is a solution to $17z = (x - y\sqrt{-5})(x + y\sqrt{-5})$ in this ring, we need to focus our attention on purely real $z \equiv 3 \bmod 10$ or $z \equiv 7 \bmod 10$.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's worth pointing out that if $a + b\sqrt{-5}$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ then it is also irreducible. So there are plenty of irreducibles that are also prime.

Let's take $6 \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, a classic example of an element that exhibits two distinct factorisations $$ 2\cdot 3 = 6 = (1+ \sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$$

> What is going wrong here – what is it that is inhibiting us from having unique factorisation?

Part of the problem is that the $(2)$ is not a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ - which is exactly what the above equation is saying: that $6 = (1+ \sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}) \in (2)$ but $1 \pm \sqrt{-5} \notin (2)$. So in some sense, the ideal $(2)$ is not irreducible.

One of the key insights of mathematicians in the late 19th century was to stop working with elements in a ring, and instead work with the ideals generated by them. For example, instead of working with $2 \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, we can work with $$(2) = \{2x : x \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\}$$

We can add and multiply ideals: if $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ are ideals, then $$\mathfrak a + \mathfrak b = \{a + b : a\in \mathfrak a, b \in \mathfrak b\}\\\mathfrak a \cdot \mathfrak b = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i :a_i \in \mathfrak a, b_i\in\mathfrak b, n \in \mathbb N\right\}$$where the product of two ideals is the ideal generated by products of elements of the two ideals.

By working with ideals, we can see what goes wrong. For example, the ideal $(2)$ is not irreducible, since we have $$(2) = (2, 1+ \sqrt{-5})\cdot(2, 1-\sqrt{-5})$$and similarly the ideals generated by $1\pm \sqrt{-5}$ are not irreducible.

The crucial fact that makes this all worthwhile is that in a certain kind of ring (called a Dedekind domain, of which $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is an example), we can not only factor ideals, but we can factorise them uniquely as a product of prime ideals. So by considering ideals instead of considering elements, we restore the property of unique factorisation.

Comment: From the classic example it follows that neither 2 nor 3 are irreducible. My understanding of the question is whether there are irreducible elements in this ring that are actually prime. If 17 is one such number, then in every case where $17|ab$ we find either $17|a$ or $17|b$. This sounds very familiar, I think it came up as a question on this StackExchange (but the question was much narrower in focus, about proving a specific irreducible in this ring is prime, I can't remember if that specific irreducible was 7 or 11).

Comment: @robertsoupe The best way to show that an element is prime is to show that the ideal generated by it is prime - ie doesn't split (eg using Dedekinds criterion, $17$ is prime since $-5$ is not a square mod $17$). I don't think it is possible to provide a full answer to the OPs question at their current level - thus the more heuristic answer.

Comment: Well, yes, that does need to be kept in mind. "Here's the answer but it's too advanced for you to understand," that might not go over well, especially with the younger askers. I'll let you know if I find that answer I was telling you about earlier, I doubt it would have been deleted.